# how to add new object type to javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, com, external, idispatch

as you know can use the follow code create a new Array Object.

```
var a = new Array();
```

now i implement a IDispatch interface for IWebBrowser,i can pass a Object to javascript,but how to handler create a custom Object like follow code,the CustomObject is undefined Object type.

```
var a = new CustomObject();
```

Comment: i want to implement it in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) function just like a normal function then use it as a custom type

```
function CustomObject(){
    //do what ever
}
```

then

```
var a = new CustomObject();
```

Also read [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function)

Comment: I believe OP will have to create the constructor from C++ and expose it via the js global object.

Comment: can handler this new operate in C++ ?